# ActivityNotFoundException After Checking ResolveInfo

Tags: android

I have a pdf url in my app that I want to open. I am checking if there is an app that can open it. If there is then I start that activity. Otherwise I am falling back to an in-app browser + google docs.

I am seeing a few ActivityNotFoundException crashes in my log at the line trying to start a pdf activity. Is something lying to me? Am I doing my checks incorrectly?

```
public void openPdf(Context context, String pdfUrl){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pdfUrl), "application/pdf");
    final ResolveInfo resolveInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0);
    // Fallback if it didn't resolve.
    if(resolveInfo == null || resolveInfo.activityInfo == null || !resolveInfo.activityInfo.exported){
        intent = InternalBrowserActivity.getInternalBrowserActivityIntent(context, createGoogleDocsPdfUrl(pdfUrl), false);
    }
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

- Before you ask, yes, `InternalBrowserActivity` is declared in the Manifest.